# Pandas read_sql changing large number IDs when reading

Tags: sql-server, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc

I transferred an Oracle database to SQL Server and all seems to have went well.  The various ID columns are large numbers so I had to use Decimal as they were too large for BigInt.

I am now trying to read the data using pandas.read_sql using pyodbc connection with ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server.   `df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT * FROM table1"),con)`

The numbers are coming out as float64 and when I try to print them our use them in SQL statements they come out in scientific notation and when I try to use `'{:.0f}'.format(df.loc[i,'Id'])` It turns several numbers into the same number such as 90300111000003078520832.  It is like precision is lost when it goes to scientific notation.

I also tried `pd.options.display.float_format = '{:.0f}'.format` before the read_sql but this did not help.

Clearly I must be doing something wrong as the Ids in the database are correct.

Any help is appreciated Thanks

Comment: Try adding `, coerce_float=False` to your `read_sql` call. That should return the column values as `Decimal` objects.

Comment: Where do you come up with this stuff...worked as usual, thanks for all your help;)

Comment: @Pearl it's in the [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pandas' [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html) method has an option named `coerce_float` which defaults to `True` and it …

> Attempts to convert values of non-string, non-numeric objects (like decimal.Decimal) to floating point, useful for SQL result sets.

However, in your case it is *not* useful, so simply specify `coerce_float=False`.

Comment: This works for SQL Server however when I try this in Oracle Number still goes to float but only on some columns and it appears that only when the number is larger than a certain amount. IE columns with sets 90100111000003066499263 go to object but columns with sets 95800111000002629236975 go to float and hence scientific notation.  Both are Number(25,0) in Oracle. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pearl - I am unable to reproduce your issue. [This code](https://pastebin.com/Rqt7jbHf) works fine for me.

Comment: So what is very strange is those IDs causing problems are the primary ID in another table and when I pull that table there is no issue.  I have also tried pulling ID's from several other tables with no issues. There are nulls in this column however I checked other ID fields with nulls and they work fine Any idea how I could diagnose this problem as I am unsure where to go from here?

Comment: Are you running SELECT on an actual table or on a view (that might involve multiple tables)?

Comment: I have limited access on the DB but it is in the table tab under my user not view in SQL Developer.  The other strange thing is it does not matter whether I use coerse_float=False or not, ALL IDs stay the same format IE all objects except these 2 columns

Comment: Does SQL Developer have an option where you can select (or perhaps right-click) a table and show the DDL to create it (CREATE TABLE …)?

Comment: It has a quick DDL. It shows the NOPARALLELLCREATE TABLE and all IDs are created the same "Id" NUMBER(25,0)

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem too, especially working with long ids: `read_sql` works fine for the primary key, but not for other columns (like the `retweeted_status_id` from Twitter API calls). Setting `coerce_float` to false does nothing for me, so instead I cast `retweeted_status_id` to a character format in my sql query.

Using psql, I do:

```
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT *, Id::text FROM table1"),con)
```

But in SQL server it'd be something like

```
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT *, CONVERT(text, Id) FROM table1"),con)
```

or

```
df = pandas.read_sql("SELECT *, CAST(Id AS varchar) FROM table1"),con)
```

Obviously there's a cost here if you're asking to cast many rows, and a more efficient option might be to pull from SQL server without using pandas (as a nested list or JSON or something else) which will also preserve your long integer formats.