# Python Pandas read_sql rounds and converts numbers

Tags: python, pandas, db2

I'm executing a query on IBM DB2 server with `ibm_db_dbi`. Here is my query:

```
connection = ibm_db_dbi.connect(hostSettings, '', '')
ret = pd.read_sql(query, connection)
```

It returns DataFrame to me. Everything is fine, but it converts all integers to float. I've another solution for that:

```
ret['AAA'] = ret['AAA'].astype(int)
```

But I have a column named as BBB(`ret['BBB']`). When I make a query on the database with a client application it returns an integer, which is `343881000298194622`. But pandas returns `3.438810002981946e+24`. I have tried to print reformatted value like that:

```
print(["{0:0.2f}".format(i) for i in ret['BBB']])
```

It prints the value as `343881000298194624.00`, not `343881000298194622.00`(The 2 at the end of the number).

What's wrong here? Why can't I print this value as database query?

Comment: that integer value exceeds the limit for a 32 bit integer.  try setting the dtype to int64 and see if that helps: ret['BBB'] = ret['BBB'].astype(dtype='int64')

Comment: @Ian it returns 343881000298194624

Comment: Then that makes me believe that there is a miss-match on the datatypes that the client returns on the results and what your sql engine receives in the ibm_db_dbi connection object.  maybe explicitly casting that column as BIGINT in your query: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_castspecification.html

Comment: this might also shed some light: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64943047/6770704